How to get a lock-screen inhibitor like caffeine working in Ubuntu 24.04 or later?
I installed Xubuntu 24.04 from Xubuntu 22, but after installing caffeine (keeps desktop from locking) and trying to run the app it fails with following warning:
/usr/bin/caffeine:24: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  import pkg_resources

I did skim over the details provided at the page referenced in the failed-to-run warning, but it appears the details are geared toward developers.
Caffeine ran fine in Xubuntu 22, so any ideas what I might be able to do to get it working in XXubuntuubu 24 ?

That is just a warning and not an error. Can you run caffeine from the terminal and post the full output?

If you are running gnome, an alternative to caffeine (debian package) is caffeine (gnome extension).  See the github link for screenshots:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/
https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine

It seems that the development of Caffeine has stopped for several years. A workaround is to use Stimulator.

You can install it from Flathub. Open a terminal and enter the commands one by one.
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub io.github.sigmasd.stimulator


I have a hot-key ( Whisker Menu > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts ) on my laptop bound to a script that toggles presentation mode ( Panel > Power Manager Plugin ):

At some point after I upgraded to 24.04 I noticed it had stopped working. However, a few tweaks seem to have fixed it:
#!/bin/bash

notify(){
    # cf. https://github.com/vlevit/notify-send.sh/blob/v0.2/notify-send.sh
    notify-send.sh -R /tmp/presentation-mode "$1"
}

pmode(){
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager \
        -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode "$@"
}

case $(pmode) in
    true)
        pmode -s false
        xset s 600 600
        xset s blank
        xset s on
        xset dpms 120 300 600
        xset +dpms
        notify "Presentation mode disabled"
        ;;
    false|*)
        pmode -s true
        xset s 0 0
        xset s noblank
        xset s reset
        xset s off
        xset dpms 0 0 0
        xset dpms force on
        xset -dpms
        notify "Presentation mode enabled"
        ;;
esac

Some of the xset commands may be unnecessary.
